# Controlling size of swf file posted to wall using graph api

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the Facebook graph api to publish a swf file on my wall, and was wondering if there is anyway I can control the height of the swf file. It looks like facebook sets the height to 259px automatically. Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the still not completely deprecated REST api, which has that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will automatically set the size to width:398px;height:259px.

The movie will be stretched to accomodate this.

If your movie is a different size, the best thing to do is to make sure it is at least the same aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there no way the dimensions can be reduced? This app called social calendar seems to be doing it, but I just can't figure out how. Would using the javascript sdk make a difference?